Perturbative analysis of pendulum via virial theorem
I am following Sivardiere, Jean. "Using the virial theorem." American Journal of Physics 54.12 (1986): 1100-1103.
The pendulum with length $L$ has equation of motion $\ddot{x}=-\omega_0^2 \sin x$, where $\omega_0=\sqrt{g / L}$. By virial theorem, we have
$$
\left\langle\dot{x}^2\right\rangle=\omega_0^2\langle x \sin x\rangle=\omega_0^2\left(\left\langle x^2\right\rangle-\frac{1}{6}\left\langle x^4\right\rangle+\frac{1}{120}\left\langle x^6\right\rangle+\ldots\right)
$$
Since the pendulum's motion is symmetric around its center, the motion of the oscillator is also symmetric around its peaks and troughs. Thus, if we shift the origin of time and perform a Fourier expansion, we would have
$$
x=A\left(\cos \omega t+\epsilon \cos 3 \omega t+c \epsilon^2 \cos 5 \omega t+\ldots\right)
$$
where $A$ is the amplitude, and $\omega$ is the angular frequency, and $\epsilon$ is a small perturbation parameter. Now it remains to perform a perturbation analysis.
Expand the virial equation to order $\epsilon^2$, we have
$$
\frac{\omega^2}{\omega_0^2}\left(1+9 \epsilon^2\right)=\left(1+\epsilon^2\right)-\frac{1}{8} A^2\left(1+4 \epsilon / 3+4 \epsilon^2\right)
$$
To allow the power series to match, we must have $A^2=z \epsilon$ and $\omega=\omega_0\left(1+a \epsilon+b \epsilon^2 \cdots\right)$ for some constants $z, a, b, \ldots$ Plugging those into the equation, and matching the coefficients of $\epsilon, \epsilon^2$, we have
$$
\begin{cases}2 a+z / 8 & =0 \\ 8+a^2+2 b+z / 6 & =0\end{cases}
$$
To solve the full system, we need another equation. This we can obtain by using the total energy of the system:
$$
\frac{1}{2} m \dot{x}_{\text {max }}^2 L^2=m g L\left(1-\cos x_{\text {max }}\right) \Longrightarrow \dot{x}_{\max }=\omega_0 \sqrt{2\left(1-\cos x_{\max }\right)}=\omega_0 x_{\max }\left(1-x_{\max }^2 / 24+x_{\text {max }}^4 / 1920+\cdots\right)
$$
Plugging in $\dot{x}_{\max }=A \omega\left(1+3 \epsilon+5 c \epsilon^2+\cdots\right)$ and $x_{\max }=A\left(1+\epsilon+c \epsilon^2+\cdots\right)$, and expanding this to order $\epsilon^2$, we have
$$
\begin{cases}a+\frac{z}{24}+2 & =0 \\ 3 a+b+4 c+\frac{z}{8}-\frac{z^2}{1920} & =0\end{cases}
$$
However, at this point, we have a problem. The solution to the equations is
$$
a\to -6,b\to -30,c\to \frac{51}{5},z\to 96
$$
And since we have $x_{max}^2 = \underbrace{A^2}_{=z\epsilon}(1 + 2\epsilon + \cdots)$, we have $\epsilon = \frac{1}{96} x_{max}^2 - \frac{2}{96^2} x_{max}^4$
However, this then gives us the period of the pendulum
$$
T = \frac{2\pi}{\omega_0}(1 + a\epsilon + b \epsilon^2 + \cdots)^{-1} = \frac{2\pi}{\omega_0}\left(1 + \frac{1}{16} x_{max}^2+ \frac{7 }{3072} x_{max}^4 + \cdots\right)
$$
where the second coefficient $\frac{7 }{3072}$ is a little off the true value $\frac{11}{3072}$.
I cannot find the error. Where did I make an error?
